# Scheme-theoretic image of the inverse image of a morphism of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a finite, surjective morphisms between noetherian, integral varieties (over $\mathbb{C}$). I am looking for conditions on $f$ under which I can say that for any closed subscheme $Z \subset Y$, the scheme-theoretic image (under $f$) of the scheme-theoretic inverse image $f^{-1}(Z)$ (obtained by taking fiber product with $f$) is isomorphic to $Z$? Do I need to assume that $f$ is smooth or a normalization map or ...?

Comment: $f$ flat is certainly enough.

Comment: @abx Thanks, how about if $f$ is a normalization map? Are there counterexamples in this case?

Comment: In fact, in your situation this property is *equivalent* to $f$ flat — see Bourbaki's *Commutative Algebra*, ch. I, §3.5, Proposition 9. So it is *never* true when $f$ is a normalization map, except if it is an isomorphism.